# Add control to StringGrid in c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to add checkbox to each row of a stringGrid in c++ builder.  As i know it is not possible for each cell of a specific column having its own child control. so what should i do

```
for (int i = 1; i < this->StringGrid1->RowCount; i++) {
    this->StringGrid1->Cells[0][i]=IntToStr(i);
    TCheckBox *l=new TCheckBox(this->StringGrid1);
    l->Name="label"+IntToStr(i);
    l->Caption="OK";
    l->Visible=true;

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need virtual tree view

Answer (score 2):

It is **technically** possible to put child controls in a `TStringGrid` (your example code is just missing an `l->Parent = StringGrid1` assignment), but it is not easy to manage such controls, especially if the grid is scrollable.

A better solution is to owner-draw the grid, by switching to a `TDrawGrid` and use its `OnDrawCell` event, so you can call the Win32 API [`DrawFrameControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162480.aspx) or [`DrawThemeBackground()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) function to draw images of checkboxes onto your grid.  You can then use a separate array/list to keep track of the checkbox "states", and use the grid's `OnMouse...` events to toggle those "states" as needed, calling the grid's `Invalidate()` method whenever a checkbox changes "state" so you can trigger a repaint to display it.  But if you go this route, you are better off switching to a virtual ListView or virtuaal TreeView instead of using a grid.

An alternative solution is to switch to a `TListView` that has its `ViewStyle` property set to `vsReport` mode and its `CheckBoxes` property set to true.